# Can I subscribe to a questions mentioning something, other than in a tag?

Tags: feature-request, support, notifications

I'd like to subscribe to all questions that mention our product / brand across some stack exchange sites (or even across the whole network).

Unfortunately, when running a search at stackexchange.com, although there are questions that mention our products in the titles, the  they have not been tagged with the names, so I can't just subscribe to a tag.

Comment: Maybe you could use favourites but that would be a bit clumsy.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a way to subscribe to all those questions but I know a search query that may help you find the posts that mention your product.

I can show you an example in the Android tag. In this example I want to find every post that contains the term *droidfu*.

Here is the query I use.

```
[android] title:droidfu body:droidfu
```

This will search every post in the Android tag for questions that have *droidfu* in their title and body.

Comment: It's not constructing the query that's the problem. It's receiving notifications when new results are posted.

Comment: I'm aware of that. I was just trying to show you an available option.